# Create delaunay triangulation in N-Dimensions from points forming non-convex surface (DelaunayTri for 5-D case)

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

I'd like to build triangulation for larger that 3 dimensions (4-6) cases. I have points representing non-convex surface. for 2D and 3D cases DelaunayTri is a way to go. What about higher dimensions?

(Original problem is to approximate some non-linear hypersurface with linear hyperplanes)

Regards,
Andrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delaunayn(), check out the matlab documentaion: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunayn.html it explains it pretty well.

Comment: Firstly Thank you for answer. I've seen that url, but my main concern - is resulted 'surface' will be let's say locally convex? Looking at mentioned URL and picture of tetrahedron there - I'd like this tetrahedron to be convex (so no triangles spanning through the center of the cube)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a convex hull rather than a delaunay triangulation in that case. Try http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhulln.html, I have never used this function myself.

Comment: Convhull will try to recreate a hull - which is not what I want.  "Qhull does not support triangulation of non-convex surfaces" I said 'locally' convex but meant triangulation. So to paraphrase, surface I want to approximate is non-convex --> this is exactly delaunay triangulation in higher dimensions (up-to 7 actually). (From wikipedia: Delaunay triangulation for a set P of points in a plane is a triangulation DT(P) such that no point in P is inside the circumcircle of any triangle in DT(P) <-- this is what I'd like to have)

Comment: They mean for any single 'triangle' or lets rather say simplex for higher dimensions. If you want a higher dimensional delaunay triangulation then delaunayn() works perfectly. If you look at the cube image in the matlab doc, no point is inside any of the tetrahedrons (or more precisely, the circumsphere or any of the tetrahedrons). Delaunay triangulation will not give you a surface, it will give you a set of simplexes of the same dimension as your dataset. If your set has 6 dimensions, you will get 6D simplexes, where a 'surface' would be 5D. Also simplexes are convex by nature...

Comment: Ok, after furhter reading I assume delaunayn() is what I want. Don't have matlab at hand, will try later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, I used it a couple of years ago (only on 3 dimensional data) and it worked fantastically. Once you get your head around all the outputs and how the tetrahedrons are stored etc its a really nice tool to use. Especially as it provides barycentric coordinates which makes interpolation within the simplexes trivial - but it doesn't sound like you'll need to do that.